# Convergence in distribution implies convergence of sequence

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables. Let $(a_n), (b_n)$ be sequences of real number. Assume that there exists random variables $X, Y$ such that $$X_n \rightarrow^{d} X, a_nX_n + b_n \rightarrow^d Y $$ where $\rightarrow^d$ indicates convergence in distribution ($F_{X_n}(x) \rightarrow F_X(x)$ for all continuity points of $F$). Then $(a_n),(b_n)$ are also convergent to some real numbers $a, b.$

I am not sure, but I think I might try showing $a_n, b_n$ are Cauchy. But I do not how and where to begin, and what I approach I should use to reach the conclusion. Please give some suggestions.

Comment: No It is false. For example if $X_n$ are all 0, you dont have any control over $a_n$.

Comment: Hint: use characteristic function

Comment: you probably want that $\Pr[X \ne 0] > 0$.

Comment: ???? Well, I should prove it, or not ? One suggestion claims it is false. Anyway, I suppose that the statement should be true. I think that I have $$\phi_{X_n}(t) \rightarrow \phi_X, e^{b_nit}\phi_{a_nX_n}(t) \rightarrow \phi_Y(t).$$

Comment: I appreciate all your hints, but can you give more details ? In my view, the hints does not give much what I should expect to do. (And, if it is alright, please confirm if I should prove it, not provide the counter example).